# error is caused when using "heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter"

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, add-on

when i use "heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter" , terminal display "An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status - banned"
what should i do to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it appeared that "due to the new filters for Heroku accounts the account was banned".

I opened up a ticket on https://help.heroku.com and they passed it on to the SendGrid support who reactivated my account. After that it all worked as expected again.

Comment: there's no way to create a ticket with that URL!

Comment: @juliangonzalez that’s unfortunate, because for me the https://help.heroku.com page shows a "Create a ticket" link at the top. Try selecting "General Platform Features" --> "Add-Ons", then scroll down and click the "Create a ticket" button. You probably need to be logged in. Maybe you can also try to get into contact with the support by finding another contact link in the footer of the Heroku page?

Comment: I realized had logged in with a non-manager user, after I switched to a manager user I was able to create the ticket. Let's see if they reply. Is there any other alternative you are aware of?

Comment: Does anyone know *why* sendgrid randomly ban heroku users? I have 20+ apps with heroku and have never abused any mailer tools (in fact, it's my first time using one), so I think the fact I'm a highly trusted heroku user should count for something (obviously not a fly by night spammer). Needless to say, it's very inconvenient.